# Span not on same line as preceding element

Tags: html, css, display

I have a `span` which follows a `nav`. Why is it not on the same line as the `nav`?

I thought inline elements such as `span` do not start on a new line.

I haven't done any CSS styling in my example.

```
<nav>
  <a href="#">HOME</a>
  <a href="#">SPEAKERS</a>
  <a href="#">SCHEDULE</a>
  <a href="#">VENUE</a>
  <a href="#">REGISTER</a>
</nav>
<span>&copy; blabla</span>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`nav` is by default `display: block` that's why `span` even being `inline` by default it will go to a new line

```css
.nav-inline {
  display: inline
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <a href="#">HOME</a>
  <a href="#">SPEAKERS</a>
  <a href="#">SCHEDULE</a>
  <a href="#">VENUE</a>
  <a href="#">REGISTER</a>
</nav>
<span>&copy; blabla</span>

<hr />

<nav class="nav-inline">
  <a href="#">HOME</a>
  <a href="#">SPEAKERS</a>
  <a href="#">SCHEDULE</a>
  <a href="#">VENUE</a>
  <a href="#">REGISTER</a>
</nav>
<span>&copy; blabla</span>
```

Answer (score 2):

`span` is a inline element but `nav` isn't. The `nav` element has already covered whole line for itself leaving no space for `span`. Hence `span` shows up in next line.
You can change `display` css property of `nav` to `inline-block` or `inline-flex` etc. to get the desired result.